# Creating an object of a different class within a class method

Tags: ruby, class, methods

I am trying to call a method that will create an object of another class. When I do, I get feedback that the object has been created, but I can't seem to to do anything with that object (such as call a method from that objects class). Here is an example:

```
class A
    def initialize

    end

    def generate
        var = B.new
    end
end

class B
    def initialize

    end

    def declare
        puts "I exist!"
    end
end

test = A.new
test.generate
var.declare
```

This returns an "Undefined local variable or method 'var'" error. Am I going about this wrong? The best I can figure is that I am creating this object only within the instance, but even when I try doing stuff with it in the instance it comes back undefined. Is there another way to do this I am not thinking of, or am I doing this wrong? Thanks!

Comment: Scope of the variable `var` seems to be limited to method `generate`.  Make it an instance variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

var is only "visible" within the `generate`method. Move it out of the class.

```
class A
    def generate
        B.new
    end
end

class B
    def declare
        puts "I exist!"
    end
end

test = A.new
var  = test.generate  # var is an instance of B
var.declare # => I exist!
```

Method chaining is also possible, avoiding variables.

```
A.new.generate.declare # => I exist!
```